# How to change network on BitcoinJS-lib with Coininfo and generate Dogecoin address?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoinjs, library

Can't find out how to **change** network on **BitcoinJS-lib** with **Coininfo** and generate **Dogecoin** address?

In a **Coininfo's** example I found this: https://github.com/cryptocoinjs/coininfo#want-to-use-with-bitcore-or-bitconjs-lib

But what to do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, and here here is my code:

```
const coininfo = require('coininfo');
var bitcoin = require("bitcoinjs-lib");

generateDOGE = function() {
    var coininfo = require('coininfo');
    var curr = coininfo.dogecoin.main;
    var frmt = curr.toBitcoinJS();

    const netGain = {
        messagePrefix: '\x19' + frmt.name + ' Signed Message:\n',
        bip32: {
            public: frmt.bip32.public,
            private: frmt.bip32.private
        },
        pubKeyHash: frmt.pubKeyHash,
        scriptHash: frmt.scriptHash,
        wif: frmt.wif
    }

    const keyPair = bitcoin.ECPair.makeRandom({ network: netGain })
    const wif = keyPair.toWIF()
    const address = bitcoin.payments.p2pkh({ pubkey: keyPair.publicKey, network: netGain });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, you would just replace the network argument in the bitcoinjs function calls to the one generated by coininfo. You'll have to figure out the message prefix (don't know if mine is correct) because it doesn't look like that's defined by coininfo.

```
const coininfo = require('coininfo')
const doge = coininfo.dogecoin.main
const dogeNetwork = doge.toBitcoinJS()
const bitcoin = require('bitcoinjs-lib')

dogeNetwork.messagePrefix = '\x18Dogecoin Signed Message:\n'
console.log('network: ' + JSON.stringify(dogeNetwork));

const keyPair = bitcoin.ECPair.makeRandom({ network: dogeNetwork })
const wif = keyPair.toWIF()
const { address } = bitcoin.payments.p2pkh({ pubkey: keyPair.publicKey, network: dogeNetwork })

console.log('address: ' + address)
```